# How do incorporate a LOCAL MLS (Multiple Listing Service) database into my website?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-applications

Has anyone created a website with MLS search/listing functionality?
Currently, brain storming how something like this is done and would like to see how others have implemented this.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thank You.
(in ASP.NET 3.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tommy,

As Dave said, the MLS "system" is very much "local" and as I discovered myself, a shambles with no agreed standard. When you say local, where are you talking about? In California, you can use the ezRETS ODBC driver:

http://www.crt.realtors.org/projects/rets/ezrets/

Check out the CRT Center for Realtor Technology:
http://www.crt.realtors.org/

Hope this is of use :-)

Answer (score 1):

MLS is fragmented and local, there is no one uber-MLS to rule them all nationwide.  Contact your local market MLS provider and ask them for rates on a subscription to their database, if they offer one.  A local Realtor would have the contacts to get you in the door.  If you're looking to provide national listings, the aforementioned fragmentation makes this a tall order.